# Task never defined: minify-js

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-concat

This is my gulpfile.js,

```
 gulp.task('concat-js',gulp.series('compile-css','minify-js'), function() {
  return gulp.src(['ui/build/**/*.js'],{"base":"./ui/build/"})
    .pipe(order([
    'ui-app.js',
    'aacoc_charts/chartsModule.js',
    '**/*.js'
    ]))
    .pipe(concatJs('application.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./ui/build'));
});
```

This is the version of gulp,
CLI version: 2.2.0
Local version: 4.0.2

But while running npm install" I am getting this error 'AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task never defined: minify-js'

Can you please help me on this

Comment: Your `minify-js` task must be defined **before** it is used in the `concat-js` task.  Same with the `compile-css` task.

Comment: This would be easier to see if you showed your entire gulpfile.js.